# Azure function activity in adf v2 not connecting to function

Tags: azure, function, azure-data-factory

I am using an azure function activity in adf v2 .But whever I am tryin to connect it always giving me error.

Error details

```
Error code3608

Troubleshooting guide

Failure typeUser configuration issue

DetailsCall to provided Azure function 'ReadMsgQueue' failed with status-'NotFound' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.

Source

Pipeline

PL_CUSTOM_COMP
```

[image: function details]

[image: queue details]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ADF troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#azure-functions), you may receive the error message when you passed incorrect Azure function details in the activity definition:

To fix this issue, make sure you had provided correct Azure function details in the activity.

[image]